# Series convergence comparison rule twist

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to decide whether the following statement is true or false:

Let $$ \sum a_n$$ $$a_n>0$$ be a convergent series.

Then there exists a sequence $$ b_n = \frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}}, \alpha>0 $$ such that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L>0 $$

How would you go at it?

Comment: Well, it isn't true with $L>0$ - you can easily construct cases where $L=0$ for all $\alpha$, such as $a_n=n^{-n}$.

Comment: If it were true, a sequence could not converge to $0$ too fast for the series to be convergent. But of course making a (positive) sequence converge to $0$ faster doesn't destroy the convergence of the series. The other end, that one can also have convergent series whose terms converge to $0$ slower than any $n^{-(1+\alpha)}$ is less obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What about $a_n = \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}$?

Comment: Didn't think of it, thanks, solves my question.

Comment: @Jiraiya: If you feel that an answer resolves your question satisfactorily, you should click on the empty tick button next to it to make it green to indicate that you accept it.

Comment: I tried when I posted the comment but it was too close to the submission of the question so it didn't let me. I will now, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Not true:
$$
a_n = 1/ 2^n 
$$

Then
$
\lim a_n/b_n = \lim{n^{1+\alpha}} / 2^n = 0
$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{n} := e^{-n}$ for all $n \geq 1$. Then $0 < a_{n} < 1/n^{2}$ for all $n \geq 1$, so $\sum a_{n}$ converges. But for all $\alpha > 0$ we have
$$
n^{1+\alpha}/e^{n} \to 0 
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false. Set for example $$a_n=n^{-\frac{5+(-1)^n}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_n$ and $d_n$ be two positive sequences so that $\sum c_n$ and $\sum d_n$ converge.

Define $$a_{n}=\begin{cases}c_k&n=2k\\d_k&n=2k-1\end{cases}$$

Show that if there are $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ that work for $c_n$ and $d_n$, that they must be the same, due to existence of $\alpha$ for $a_n$.